# Reading DOM attribute in protractor

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to read the HTML manifest attribute using protractor. My code snippet is:

```
element(by.css('html')).getAttribute('manifest');
```

But I am getting following error and I dont know how to fix it.
Message:

```
  Failed: Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of Error while waiting f
 Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could b
either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client
ide navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http
/git.io/v4gXM for details"
Stack:
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

**"window.angular is undefined** error could be because of below 2 reasons
1. Your page is not angular
2. The ng-app attribute is not on the 'body'

Refer to the official documentation @ [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/42)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` if the webpage does not contain angular in it.